# redirecting multipiped output to a file handle in perl

Tags: perl

I want to redirect this awk output to the file handle but no luck.

Code:

```
open INPUT,"awk -F: '{print $1}'/etc/passwd| xargs -n 1 passwd -s | grep user";
while (my $input=<INPUT>)

{
...rest of the code
}
```

Error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test line 12.
readline() on closed filehandle INPUT at ./test line 13.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `$1` in the string you've passed is making Perl look for a variable `$1` which you've not defined. Try escaping the `$` in the string by putting a `\` in front of it.

Because the string is not valid it doesn't do the open which then produces your second error.

Comment: The string is perfectly valid. That the output cannot be retrieved via the file handle is due to no `|` being at the end of the string.

Comment: The string is not valid in that it's incorrectly formed because he hasn't escaped the $, and thus isn't the string he thinks it is. You're correct about the missing '|'.

Comment: The string is syntactically correct from both Perl's and awk's points of view. Not being valid and not doing what someone wants them to do are two completely distinct things.

Comment: Code in Q has way more errors so you must catch all these bugs since he accepted your answ xD

Answer (score 4):

The error message shown is not directly related to the question in the subject.

1. In order to open a pipe and retrieve the result in Perl you have to add "`|`" at the very end of the `open` call.
2. The error message comes from the fact that Perl interprets the `$1` you use in that double-quoted string. However, your intention was to pass that verbatim to `awk`. Therefore you have to escape the `$` on the Perl side with `\$`.
3. There's a space missing in front of the `/etc/passwd` argument.

Summary: this should work better:

```
open INPUT,"awk -F: '{print \$1}' /etc/passwd| xargs -n 1 passwd -s | grep user|";
```

However, you should also check for errors etc.

Comment: Thanks Mortiz. That works. :) Once i added pipe at the end of the one liner it worked. I have few doubts related to File Handles

1. when i add "<" as second argument in "open" it does not work. why so?

2. I didnt not remove space after /etc/passwd still it worked. Does space play a vital role in File Handles?

3. I am bit confused with this escaping \$1 . As if i try `awk -F: '{print \$1}' /etc/passwd` from the shell awk program throws an error but how does the same work when it is inside perl ?

Comment: 1. `<` opens a file, not a process/pipe. 2. If there is no space then awk treats the `/etc/passwd` as being part of the code to execute, not as the file name to read from. 3. Perl sees the `\` and knows not to treat the next character `$` specially. So Perl removes that `\` but keeps `$1` verbatim, and `awk` only sees the string `print $1`.

Comment: You use `|-` to write to a process and `-|` to read from a process in the (preferred) 3-argument form of `open`.  See [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for details.